# How to use custom nuget folder in .NET Framewrok with PackageReference?

Tags: .net, gitlab, msbuild, nuget, packagereference

there is a legacy .NET Framework solution with many projects.
CI pipeline (Gitlab) has several jobs:

1. Restores nugets to the specific folder and takes the folder as an artifact.
2. Uses the artifact nugets to build the solution
3. ...
4. Uses the artifact for another tasks.

I need to migrate the solution to the latest .NET version, but I can't use the big bang approach, cause it would require a lot of effort and would stop other development tasks. The first step is to migrate from packages.config to PackageReference.

After the migration, I've faced a problem. Since PackageReference packages are maintained in the global-packages folder I can't take them as an artifact and reuse in another jobs.

I've tried:

1. Add a nuget.config file with xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<config>
    <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="..\packages" />
</config>
</configuration>
```

2. Restore nugets using command line: `nuget restore Solution.sln -Force`. The globalPackagesFolder parameter works, command line restore nuget packages to the custom folder.
3. Gitlab job configured to take "packages" folder as an artifact and add the folder in the next jobs where these nugets are required. Works as expected.
4. Build solution using command line: `msbuild Solution.sln /maxcpucount /nologo /property:Configuration=Debug /verbosity:minimal /t:Rebuild /nr:false /p:RestorePackagesPath=packages | Write-Host` - Fail!

Sadly, but msbuild can't see nuget packages even with `p:RestorePackagesPath=packages` parameters and throws a lot of errors with missing reference text. Could you please explain why msbuild can't use custom folder packages? How I could fix my code/configs to make it work?